# Simple Laravel 5 Seeding: Closure object cannot have properties

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to seed some files, yet I get:

**[Error Exception] Closure object cannot have properties**

Not sure what is wrong, since I do very basic seeding.

Here are my files:

**all.php** in tests/factories/all.php

```
$factory('App\User', [
    'name'     => $faker->name,
    'email'    => $faker->email,
    'password' => password_hash('000400', PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
]);
```

This is the command I am using:

**php artisan db:seed --class="UserTableSeeder"**

This is my UserTableSeeder:

```
public function run()
{
//  User::create([
        // 'name'     => 'Rainbow Warrior',
        // 'email'    => 'email@exmaple.org',
        // 'password' => password_hash('123456', PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
//  ]);

    TestDummy::times(20)->create('App\User');
}
```

Comment: The `-v` flag is always useful for debugging these sorts of problems.  php artisan db:seed --class="UserTableSeeder" -v   The v stands for verbose, and you'll get a stack trace that shows you which line threw the error.

Comment: These types of information are missing in the docs.

Comment: please forgive me for downvoting. I haven't read it well! if you do an edit, I'll upvote your question, but giving an answer just for a typo is a bit cheap isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a typo inside my all.php that looked like this:

```
$factory('App\Comment', [
    'user_id'   => 'factory:App\User',
    'question'  => $factory->sentence,
    'answer'    => $factory->text
]);
```

If you look closely, you will notice, that instead of **$faker**, I wrote **$factory**. Well... fair enough.